# SQL Server metadata in intellisense?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I haven't been able to find a a SQL Server intellisense tool that provides meta data info (like table and column description infor) in tooltips. I could've sworn that Red Gate supported it but I can't seem to figure out how. Devarts SQL Complete does not appear to.

Are there any intellisense tools that do this? 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you hover the cursor over the object in a query window, SQL Prompt will show a tooltip with the MS_Description displayed. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Not sure why I didn't notice that before. I guess I was expecting it to be part of the intellisense popup window. ty

Comment: If you have 'Display Object Definitions' checked in your options, upon highlighting an item in the suggestions box you will get a further dialog with the SQL script. At the bottom of the script is the SQL definition of the MS_Description extended property. But hovering your mouse pointer over the object is a lot easier! :)

Comment: Is there any way of show table/column descriptions in vanilla SSMS?

Comment: Not easily as it's strangely hidden. You have to right click on the object in the Object Explorer, select Properties and then Extended Properties. You can optinallly generate an html report using SQL Doc (if you own this tool) and publish this somewhere that is accessible by developers.