# Documentation comments for function parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to figure out how I can give the user "suggestions" via intellisense for the different input parameters (description what a certain variable stands for) in SQL Server 2016 for self-created functions:

```
USE [XXXXXXXX]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- =============================================
-- Author:      XXXXXX
-- Create date: 2018-01-12
-- Description: --------------------XXxxxxx
-- =============================================
CREATE FUNCTION [XXX].[RemoveStringBetween] 
(
    @string VARCHAR(MAX),   -- input string
    @first INT,             -- position of first character of substring to be removed
    @second INT             -- position of last character of substring to be removed
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(max)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @res VARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @res = (SUBSTRING(@string, 0, @first) + SUBSTRING(@string, @second + 1, LEN(@string) - @second));

    RETURN @res;
END
GO
```

Comment: There's no sort of standardised comment format that will be picked up and used in intellisense by any of the Microsoft tools AFAIK.

Comment: You are asking about *documentation comments*, not "suggestions". *Some* languages use comments for documentation. SQL Server uses [extended properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190243(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Apart from that, Intellisense is a product feature. SSMS at least doesn't display extended procedures or comments, Function level ex props appear in the function's property box. As [Aaron Bertrand explains](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/84280/how-to-format-documentation-in-ms-description-extendedproperties) in dba.stackexchange.com tool support is so inconsistent you probably shouldn't bother

Comment: On the other hand third-party tools [work better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363551/sql-server-metadata-in-intellisense). Documentation scripts [like this one](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/sql-tools/towards-the-self-documenting-sql-server-database/) can use them to generate docs from a DB. Using nicely formatted comments source control though could be even better. A rather dumb script could extract markdown sections from the SQL files in a VS Database project.

Comment: Thanks for comments. It seems that I mistakenly though that there is an option to display some comments in the popup which appears when you write "SELECT function()...." like e.g. in Visual Studio or so.

Answer (score 0):

That’s a great desire and it’d be pretty useful. Descriptions for columns are displayed, but why no parameter descriptions?

An [older article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms190243(v=sql.105)#objects-with-no-extended-property-support) says something along those lines:

> *Extended properties cannot be defined on […] function parameters […] and stored procedures.*

---

However, [**`sp_addextendedproperty`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addextendedproperty-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) allows syntax like this:

```
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty
    @name = N'Description',
    @value = N'This is a documentation.',
    @level0type = 'SCHEMA',
    @level0name = 'dbo',
    @level1type = 'FUNCTION', -- or 'PROCEDURE'
    @level1name = 'fn_user_function', -- or procedure name
    @level2type = 'PARAMETER',
    @level2name = '@param';
```

It does *not* execute idempotently and frowns upon a missing at sign, so it seems to reflect the user’s intent. Also, if you generate a `CREATE` script afterwards, adding the property is included.

It’s also included in the respective system table:

```
SELECT  obj.name AS 'Object',
        type_desc AS 'Type',
        prop.name AS 'Property',
        prop.value AS 'Value'
FROM sys.extended_properties prop
JOIN sys.all_objects obj
ON prop.major_id = obj.object_id
WHERE   class_desc = 'PARAMETER' AND
        type_desc IN ('SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION', 'SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE')
ORDER BY create_date DESC;
```

Anyhow, the info isn’t displayed anywhere in my configuration. I wonder if it works with some other versions of SSMS or using different settings. The article on [IntelliSense Parameter Info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/parameter-info-intellisense?view=sql-server-ver16) looks promising, but wasn’t applicable in my case. I’m excited to know!

---

In the meantime, I suggest this:

1. Keep adding *good* (i.e. vitally concise) inline comments after the parameter declaration.
2. Use *good* (i.e. essentially descriptive) parameter names.

   - Plausible, intelligible and generally understandable code is its best documentation. A well-named identifier can save comments and documentation altogether.
   - You can use up to 128 characters (it’s a `SYSNAME`).
   - Random improvement suggestions from the OP’s code sample:

     - `@string` ➔ `@InputText`
     - `@first` ➔ `@FirstCharPosition`
     - `@second` ➔ `@CharPosition_Last`

*(Yet this good advice is a mere stand-in until I find out how added properties are actually displayed …)*